# autofill textBox in vb

Tags: vb.net, autofill

I need to autofill text box when any character is entered.
The query for  Me.QuickSearchTableAdapter1.GetDataByFirstName(FirstNamePri.Text) is

```
SELECT        firstNamePri FROM      Customer WHERE        (firstNamePri LIKE @firstName)
```

> Private Sub FirstNamePri_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
>   System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles FirstNamePri.KeyPress
>
> ```
>     Dim txtItems As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
>     Dim search As ArfDynamicsDataSet.QuickSearchDataTable = _
>     Me.QuickSearchTableAdapter1.GetDataByFirstName(FirstNamePri.Text+"%")
>
>     Dim dbValues As String
>
>     For Each row As DataRow In search.Rows
>
>          dbValues = row("firstNamePri").ToString()
>         dbValues = dbValues.ToLower()
>         txtItems.Add(dbValues)
>
>
>     Next
>
>     FirstNamePri.AutoCompleteCustomSource = txtItems
>
> End Sub
> ```

When I enter a character and that character is not present in db the textBox stays empty and the characters i enter are also being deleted

I have selected AutoCompleteMode to Suggest and AutoCompleteMode to CustomSource

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong.

EDIT: If I use keypress event of another textbox say TextBox1 and autofill FirstNamePri frrom TextBox1 event it works. It should work on keyPress of FirstNamepri

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
Dim textParam = FirstNamePri.Text + "%"
Dim search As ArfDynamicsDataSet.QuickSearchDataTable = _
          Me.QuickSearchTableAdapter1.GetDataByFirstName(textParam)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function FetchProductSpareList(prefixText As String) As String()
    Dim dbinventory As New DCInventoryNewDataContext()
    Dim CompanyId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("CompanyID").ToString())

    Dim ProductNames = ( _
    Join P In dbinventory.Products On S.ProductId = P.id _
    Join C In dbinventory.SpareReceiptCodes On S.Id = C.StoreId _
    Where P.CompanyID = CompanyId AndAlso C.Active = True AndAlso _
                      P.ProductName.StartsWith(prefixText)).Distinct()
    Dim items As String() = New String(ProductNames.Count() - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each Product As var In ProductNames
        items.SetValue(Product.ProductName, i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return items
End Function
```