# Directory Paths within a Text Box within VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I've seen some applications that as you type a path into a text box is builds out a list of available directories and or files.

I'm trying to replicate in VB.NET using VS2008 and can't figure out how to get started.  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

--George

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

AutoComplete should work for you:

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/AutoCompleteGuide.htm

[Vb.net + AutoComplete in textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152144/vb-net-autocomplete-in-textboxes)

[autofill textBox in vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540105/autofill-textbox-in-vb)

Comment: Autocomplete!  Awesome..  I'll review the links shortly.

Comment: AutoComplete did it..

Text Box Properties = AutoCompleteMode = Suggest & AutoCompleteSource = AllSystemResources

This allows me to start typing and see the directories..  Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

AutoComplete did it..

Text Box Properties = AutoCompleteMode = Suggest & AutoCompleteSource = AllSystemResources

This allows me to start typing and see the directories..  Thanks for the point in the right direction!